# Remove Tabs panel - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

How can I deactivate the tab called "Tabs" showed in the picture below?

I would like that my VS stays with the default tab, not this Tabs consuming half of the space

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual Studio main menu Tools - Options - Environment - Tabs and Windows - Set tab layout - select Top.

Answer (score 0):

For **Visual Studio 2022**

Right-Click on top of the tabs panel and you'll have the options to set it's layout. Then (Select Top)